# Is it possible replace one character by two using maketrans?

Tags: python, string, translation

I want to replace æ character with ae. How can I obtain it? Here is my try with `maketrans` and `translate`:

```
word = 'være'
letters = ('å','ø', 'æ')
replacements = ('a','o','ae')

table = word.maketrans(letters, replacements)
#table = word.maketrans(''.join(letters),''.join(replacements))
word_translated = word.translate(table)
print(word_translated)
```

It generates errors:

```
TypeError: maketrans() argument 2 must be str, not tuple
ValueError: the first two maketrans arguments must have equal length
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You need to supply a `dict` as argument to `maketrans()`. As stated in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.maketrans)

> If there is only one argument, it must be a dictionary mapping Unicode ordinals (integers) or characters (strings of length 1) to Unicode ordinals, **strings (of arbitrary lengths)** or None. Character keys will then be converted to ordinals.

```
word = 'være'
letters = ('å','ø', 'æ')
replacements = ('a','o','ae')

table = word.maketrans(dict(zip(letters, replacements)))
word_translated = word.translate(table)
print(word_translated)
```

output

```
vaere
```