# Maketrans use dict and remove list of word

Tags: python, string

I passed a dictionary to maketrans to replace a symbol with multiple character ([Is it possible replace one character by two using maketrans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53897804/is-it-possible-replace-one-character-by-two-using-maketrans)), however i also want to pass string containing symbol to be removed by maketrans. However maketrans does not accept second argument if the first argument was a dictionary and not a string.

Here is example code of what i wanted to do (the code below does not work)

```
txt = "Good night Sam!"

x = {"S": "J", "a": "o", "m": "hn"}
z = "odnght"

mytable = txt.maketrans(x, z)

print(txt.translate(mytable))
```

The expected outcome was to replace the `txt` into "G i John!". The code above throws the following error

```
TypeError: first maketrans argument must be a string if there is a second argument
```

Is there any way to make maketrans accept z argument when dictionary is passed as first argument? if not possible, is there any workaround to this while still using maketrans?

Comment: If you use the dictionary option for `.maketrans()`, you indicate deletions by adding dict keys that map to `None`.  `x = {"S": "J", "a": "o", "m": "hn", **dict.fromkeys("odnght")}` would work as input to one-argument `maketrans()` (on a sufficiently recent Python version).

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) :

> This static method returns a translation table usable for [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate).
> If there is only one argument, it must be a dictionary mapping Unicode ordinals (integers) or characters (strings of length 1) to Unicode ordinals, strings (of arbitrary lengths) or None. Character keys will then be converted to ordinals.
> If there are two arguments, they must be strings of equal length, and in the resulting dictionary, each character in x will be mapped to the character at the same position in y. If there is a third argument, it must be a string, whose characters will be mapped to None in the result.

This means that there are three different *signatures* for this function :

```py
1: maketrans(dict_mapping)
2: maketrans(str_map_from, str_map_to)
3: maketrans(str_map_from, str_map_to, str_map_none)
```

If you insist on having a dictionnary, only the first one fits your need. So we need to pass a dictionnary having the desired content :

```py
from itertools import repeat

txt = "Good night Sam!"

x = {"S": "J", "a": "o", "m": "hn"}
z = "odnght"

mytable = txt.maketrans(x | dict(zip(z, repeat(None))))  # TypeError on Python < 3.9

result = txt.translate(mytable)
print(result)
assert result == "G i John!"
```

and for Python < 3.9 :

```py
from itertools import repeat, chain

txt = "Good night Sam!"

x = {"S": "J", "a": "o", "m": "hn"}
z = "odnght"

mytable = txt.maketrans(dict(chain(x.items(), zip(z, repeat(None)))))

result = txt.translate(mytable)
print(result)
assert result == "G i John!"
```

What we do is create a dictionnary with all the mappings we want, which is those from `x`, then for each char in `z` we have pair it with a `None`.
`itertools` (from the stdlib) is useful here, but creating a dict with all values being `None` can also be done with a *dict comprehension* :

```py
mytable = txt.maketrans(dict(**x, **{removed_char: None
                                     for removed_char in z}))
```